# matlab - symbol order in qammod

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to simulate QAM with arbitrary symbol mapping.

Matlab help page says I just need to use the format: y =qammod(x,M,symOrder).

```
M=16;k = log2(M);n = 10000;dataIn = randi([0 1],n,1);
dataInMatrix = reshape(dataIn,length(dataIn)/k,k);
dataSymbolsIn = bi2de(dataInMatrix);

vec = randperm(16)-1;
dataMod = qammod(dataSymbolsIn,M,0,vec);
```

Matlab returns error 'Invalid symbol set ordering.'

I'm wondering if this is a problem with Matlab version since help page is for 2016a but school computer has 2015b.

Comment: Then look at the local documentation: `doc qammod` or `help qammod`. Or look at the [archived documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html).

Comment: I looked at help and ended up using modulation using modem.qammod instead

Comment: You can answer, and even accept, your own question. Feel free to write an answer that explains better the problem and specifically how you solved it so other with the same issue might be helped.